# Stripping or replacing HTML tags in rich text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp-3.0

I am using [JQuery Text Editor - jqueryte.com](http://jqueryte.com/) for providing users with a simple, light weight rich text editor. On the back end I am using PHP, specifically CakePHP 3

Everything works well for the most part. However, I noticed that sometimes when I copy text from websites and paste it in the text editor it saves it verbatim with all the HTML tags. Not that this is bad, but certain tags like `<p>` and `<div>` are causing issues while displaying the content.

So far, I have come up with the following remediation choices

1. Use javascript / PHP to strip select tags before save - however this may interfere with the display of information as it would remove indentation etc
2. Switch over to an alternate text editor like CKEditor - I noticed that they have replacement rules in their configuration options. I would like this to be a last resort, also if anyone has any experience in configuring CKEditor, I would appreciate insight

Any other suggestions, options I may not have considered? Help is much appreciated...

Comment: paste as plain text could be one option.

Comment: I cant control what the user will do - unless there is a programmatic way to force paste as plain text